# Need help getting links set in wordpress admin dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I am just trying to get the links set in the dashboard, which is under Appearance >> Customize >> Menus >> Top Menu but I cannot seem to find a single way to do it on the internet. I want to fetch the ones set in this menu

[image]

I have tried everything I found on the internet from

```
<?php var_dump($GLOBALS['menu']) ?>
```

to

```
<?php wp_get_nav_menu_items('primary'); ?>
```

I looked at over 60 webpages and I just cannot find how to do it. Can someone tell me how to get them? I just want to let the user define the links in Top Menu so they can dynamically change the links at any time

Comment: You know WP have custom WP_Query class, you can use that and fetch all types of menu items as WP uses post type "nav_menu_item" for menu links. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: I am new to wordpress. Can you make an example?

Comment: Got it working with Social Media Menu but not Top menu